# Remove Dash/Hyphen From WooCommerce Product Permalink

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, woocommerce

We are migrating a 5,000 SKU website to WooCommerce. In order to accommodate this and make the 301s as accurate as possible, we want to remove all hyphens/dashes from the product permalink in WooCommerce.

For example:

www.website.com/product/product-name/

Becomes

www.website.com/product/productname/

Any advice on how to do this? We already have the products imported, so it would be ideal to write a piece of code that would automatically strip the dash.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you access the URLs/in what format do you have them? It is quite simple to remove an hyphen from a single string, do you have trouble getting to this URL string?

Comment: It is all via WordPress. WordPress automatically adds dashes to replace spaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the URL as a String? If so using `str_replace` PHP function you can simply replace "-" with "" like this

```
$originalURL = "www.website.com/product/product-name/"
$newURL = str_replace("-","",$originalURL);
```

Comment: Where would we put that? In the functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Oh if you are working with Wordpress, in the dashboard there is an 'edit' button for the links in each page. You can use it to edit the link.

1. In the Dashboard, 
   `Pages`-> select your page
2. On the top of page you can see `Permalink: www.website.com/product/product-name/` and the `edit` button.

You can edit permalink of each page using that.